# MQTT - How to change the behaviour of the default parser for JSON on the CE (SenML)?

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I have a gateway fromKhomp manufacturer which delivers packages in the following format (SenML):

```
message:  [
    {
       "bn": "000D6FFFFE642E09",
       "bt": 1611339204
    },
    {
       "n": "model",
       "vs": "nir21z"
    },
    {
       "n": "Geladeira Temp",
       "u": "Cel",
       "v": 4.0
   }
```

When I connect to the Thingsboard platform, the internal GW/Parser breaks as an array before the Input in the Root Rule Chain, and threats as individual packets, but since the first position in this array corresponds to the device ID (MAC) I need to have the whole message to be parser in a script. Does anyone know a way to get the information before the GW parses the message?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Thingsboard CE then I think you will need to first forward the data to a middleware service to restructure the payload. If you are familiar with AWS Lambda you can do it there.

It would just be a simple script that takes an input payload, restructures, and then forwards to your Thingsboard deployment.

If you're using Thingsboard PE then you can use Integration/Data Converters to do this.